# How to regroup commands in a shell to avoid repeated redirections?

Tags: shell

I have a script where I output three things into a file. I'd like to call the `>` operator only once. Is there a way to describe a block of instructions? Should I use a function?

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(ls src)
 do
  f=${i%.*}
  echo 'first bit' > dist/$i.htm
  perl myScriptThatOutputsSecondBit.pl >> dist/$i.htm
  echo 'third bit' >> dist/$i.htm
 done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `compound/group` command:

To run it in a current-shell,

```
 {echo 'first bit';perl myScriptThatOutputsSecondBit.pl;echo 'third bit';} > dist/$i.htm
```

To run it in a sub-shell,

```
 (echo 'first bit';perl myScriptThatOutputsSecondBit.pl;echo 'third bit') > dist/$i.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple log function, this would be more efficient. e.g.

```
log(){
   echo $1 >> dist/$i.htm
}
```

and then call it from the script:

```
for i in $(ls src)
do
    f=${i%.*}
    log 'first bit'
    perl myScriptThatOutputsSecondBit.pl >> dist/$i.htm
    log 'third bit'
done
```

Comment: How would that be more efficient?

Comment: Efficiency put aside, you repeat the path twice which is precisely what I wanted to avoid

Comment: Efficient in the sense logically and code looks more modular. The answer by John is perfect for this case, but what if you have long and complex shell script with many such echo statements? You'll group 100's of commands and redirect the output of all at the end ?

Comment: more modular ? You precise the path in the function AND in the main body. I think the other answer is way more modular than that! Thanks anyway.